# Why the console prints error text from the JTextArea (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

The problem is: 
**When I print the text from `JTextArea` to the console:**

```
System.out.println(textArea.toString());
```

I get output like this:

```
javax.swing.JTextArea[,0,0,522x170,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicBorders$MarginBorder@43413332,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],colums=0,columWidth=0,rows=0,rowHeight=0,word=false,wrap=false]
```

Can anyone help me to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.println(textArea.toString());
```

That displays the properties of the text area, not the text in the text area.

Most Objects in Java has a custom `toString()` method to display information about the properties of the Object.

You want:

```
System.out.println(textArea.getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getText()` method to get the displayed text, not `toString()`.